javac error source option 5 is no longer supported. Use 6 or later
I tried to install Trimmomatic-0.39 in my Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS system.
When I tried "ant" command:
Thank you in advance for your great help!
Best,
Yue
compile:
[javac] Compiling 41 source files to /home/yueli/sph_data/Trimmomatic-0.39/dist/build
[javac] warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 5
[javac] error: Source option 5 is no longer supported. Use 6 or later.
[javac] error: Target option 1.5 is no longer supported. Use 1.6 or later


I dwonliaded the wrong version of Trimmomication. It should be binary, not source.
